# Exception from Tracker afterFlush function: undefined using Materialize modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, rendering, materialize

I am attempting to run [materialize modal](http://materializecss.com/modals.html) within my Meteor app. I have a template called "classrooms" where i am using an onRendered method like so:

```
 Template.classrooms.onRendered(function () {

   $('.modal-trigger').leanModal();

});
```

if I reload my page, the modal works fine. However once I navigate out of my page or reload my page on a different route and navigate back to "/classrooms/" I get the following error:

> Exception from Tracker afterFlush function:

Followed by:

```
TypeError: $(...).leanModal is not a function
    at null.<anonymous> (classrooms.js:18)
    at template.js:116
    at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (template.js:457)
    at fireCallbacks (template.js:112)
    at null.<anonymous> (template.js:205)
    at view.js:107
    at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (view.js:538)
    at view.js:106
    at Object.Tracker._runFlush (tracker.js:497)
    at onGlobalMessage (setimmediate.js:102)
```

Has anybody run into this or know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what was going on. I was actually calling jQuery twice within my app. Let me explain.

Every meteor app is loaded with jQuery automatically once you call `meteor create` at the moment you create your app. View more info on Atmospheres page: https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/jquery

I was also manually inserting jquery on my layout.

By having both of these, this weird bug presented itself. However once I realized this and removed jQuery from the layout, everything fell into place. So make sure you are not initializing jQuery on your app to avoid these bugs.

Comment: I have run into a similar issue. Your answer isn't that clear, kindly specify in code how you were manually inserting jquery in your layout.

Comment: I found out that in my *.js files replacing "onRemdered" in Template.templateName.onRendered to "helpers" removed the issue. I now have  Template.templateName.helpers. I have no idea why this helps but I hope this helps someone out there!